# Android media player skipping forward

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Im not able to skip the audio to a forward time.

**seekto** only works for going back and not forward. How do i skip the audio to 10 second forward

Present Code

```
player.pause();
player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() + 10000);
player.start();
```

Comment: You can use exoplayer android.
all these controls are handled https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer